# First Name and Last Name must be Unique Together in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, unique

I know that using the following codes will make each column have unique values, but what if I want a full name to be unique?

```
CREATE TABLE people (first_name varchar2(32) unique,
                     last_name varchar2(32) unique);
```

this will make each attribute unique on its own, but I need to make them both together unique, like If I have a name "James Smith", I don't want this name to be repeated again, but its ok if there was a "James Sunderland" guy.

Comment: Do you really have to validate all business logic in database? I'm just curious.

Comment: You do know that first_name, last name is not really a unique combination right? Even a small organization can end up with dups easily especially if they hire father and son combos like a doctor's office.

Comment: @win, uniquess must be validated in the database or you WILL have data integrity problems.

Comment: Guys this is just an example, I just wanted to know how to do it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the `UNIQUE` constraint on the combination of the two columns:

```
CREATE TABLE people 
  ( first_name varchar2(32) , 
    last_name varchar2(32) ,
    UNIQUE ( first_name, last_name )
  ) ;
```